# Engaging ways to mark recent changes made by the user

Tags: web-app

In a web application where the users edit records in a large database, and normally start off by looking at a list of 10-30 records, what are the best practices of marking records that were changed by this user over, say, last day or two?

Comment: I think you need to tailor the design to the application, so it is difficult to say what the best practice would be. However, normally you would look at a range of visual cues including font variation, status change indicators and other ways to highlight the record to make it stand out.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I want to find the middle ground between making the notification too noisy and distracting, and no notification at all.

Comment: Is this notification just for the user to let them know what has changed, or is this notification for all users to let them know who has been changing what?

Comment: Just for the user, as a sanity check, or a minor motivation to get more things done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either a filter option (to only show records that were recently edited by the user) or by using a status indicator in the table (like a pencil icon next to a relevant data item in each row).

Plenty of things depend greatly on who's using this and why. Consider asking others who use your application what they would expect or like to see. Conventions are great unless your use case or user base lacks... well... convention.